# Draw rectange with 3:2 aspect ratio on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am attempting to draw a rectangle with 3:2 aspect ratio. 
I am using OpenCV to detect objects in image. So from the output values I am drawing a rectangle with min X, min Y, max X, max Y. Now I need to make that rectangle have a 3:2 aspect ratio from the starting points i.e min x and min Y.

> It should not go beyond the original image max X and max Y and the
>   rectangle should not be lesser than existing rectangle around the
>   detected objects.

Comment: You need **any** 3:2 new rectangle (`r_new`) such that (i) the intersection of `r_new` and `r_old` is equal to `r_old` and (ii) `r_new` should not extrapolate the "original" image. Is that correct?

Comment: yes... @Berriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can solve this:

```
# determine the y / x length of the rectangle
len_X = maxX - minX
len_Y = maxY - minY

# determine the largest side, this will be the 3 in the aspect ratio
if len_X > len_Y:
    # check if the shorter side is larger than a 3:2 ration
    if len_Y > len_X * (3/2):
        # if so, increase larger side to 3:2 ratio
        len_X = len_Y * 1.5
    else:
        # else, increase shorter side to 3:2 ratio
        len_Y = len_X * (3/2) 
else:
    # same as above
    if len_X > len_Y * (3/2):
        len_Y = len_X * 1.5
    else:
        len_X = len_Y * (3/2) 

# if the rectangle exceeds the image, constrain the rectangle
# other option (commented): move the starting position
if minX + len_X > img.shape[1]:
    len_X = img.shape[1]-minX
    #minX = img.shape[1]-len_X
if minY + len_Y > img.shape[0]:
    len_Y = img.shape[0]-minY
    #minY = img.shape[0]-len_Y

# draw the rectangle
cv2.rectangle(img, (minX, minY), (minX + len_X, minY + len_Y), (0,0,255),1)
```

Comment: Hi J.D i tried your answer its giving 3/2.5 ratio instead of 3/2

Comment: Can you provide an example minX, maxX, minY, maxY?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the new box size so that its w:h is 3:2. And then trim the box if one of its sides is longer than that of the image's.

After determining the box size, we then calculate the box center. By default, the box center remains the same, but it will be shifted if the box cross the boundary of the image.

Finally we can use box size and box center to calculate the coordinates of box corners.

```
import cv2

def draw_rectangle(img, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y):
    # resize box to 3:2(only enlarge it)
    # determine the box_w and box_h
    box_w, box_h = max_x-min_x, max_y-min_y
    if box_w/box_h < 3/2:
        box_w = int(box_h*(3/2))
    else:
        box_h = int(box_w*(2/3))

    # trim the box so it won't be bigger than image
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    box_w = w if box_w > w else box_w
    box_h = h if box_h > h else box_h

    # determine the center of box

    # the default box center
    box_center_x = (min_x+max_x)//2
    box_center_y = (min_y+max_y)//2

    # shift the box if it cross the boundary
    if box_center_x + box_w//2 > w:
        box_center_x = w - box_w//2
    elif box_center_x - box_w//2 < 0:
        box_center_x = box_w//2
    if box_center_y + box_h//2 > h:
        box_center_y = h - box_h//2
    elif box_center_y - box_h//2 < 0:
        box_center_y = box_h//2

    # calculate the corner of the box
    min_x, max_x = box_center_x - box_w//2, box_center_x + box_w//2
    min_y, max_y = box_center_y - box_h//2, box_center_y + box_h//2
    cv2.rectangle(img, (min_x, min_y), (max_x, max_y), (255,0,0), thickness=10)
    return img

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = 0, 0, 400, 230
img = draw_rectangle(img, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: i need it for 3:2 ratio but you did for 2:3, anyway it worked by swapping it. and one more thing 3/2 result 1.5 which is float so we supposed to use 3.0/2.0 instead 3/2.

Comment: Sorry for that but I assumed you mean h:w=3:2. And I am using Python 3 so the code work for me.

Comment: I don't think so. I can't see it now.

Comment: @Codecracker Still anything I can help you?